# Did any PS3 games come in a Dual Layer 50GB Blu-ray disk?

Tags: ps3, physical-media

A standard Single Layer Blu-ray can hold 25GB, but a Dual Layer disc can hold 50GB.

Did any PS3 Games came in a 50GB disc? Is there a way to identify them?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, several games used more than 25 GB, for example:

- [Killzone 3](https://www.justpushstart.com/2011/01/just-how-big-is-killzone-3-in-terms-of-size/) is 41.5 GB
- [Uncharted 3 GOTY](https://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/topic/177463-uncharted-3-goty-edition-435-gb/) is 43.5 GB
- [God of War: Ascension](https://www.easygameshobbies.com.ar/us/products/god-of-war-ascension-ps3/) is 34 GB

And unless they came in more than one discs, as for Final Fantasy XIII, they were definitely dual layer 50 GB discs.

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but FF13 having 3 discs for the X360 release. If I'm not mistaken, the PS3 release was only 1 disc

Comment: @Wondercricket didn't know that. Then we have another one, since FFXIII for PS3 is 39.4 GB

Answer (score 3):

Although I was unable to find an authoritative source on the subject, it would seem that discs manufactured by Sony have a 4-character code etched around the inner ring representing the type of disk it is:

- BVSS for single layer Blu-ray movies
- BVDL for double layer Blu-ray movies
- BPSS for single layer PlayStation3 games
- BPDL for double layer PlayStation3 games

I have confirmed that my copies of *MGS4* and *Uncharted 3* have BPDL and two barcodes while *Ratchet & Clank Future: ToD* has BPSS and a single barcode around the hole, visible under the disc - as in, not on the side with the printed label.

There's a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Digital_Audio_Disc_Corporation#Manufacturing_codes) that lists more codes but it also lacks sources, so take that with a grain of salt.